# Submit iPhone App for limited Devices

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am on the edge of submitting my first iPhone Application.

So, now I have little confusion in the submitting process..

My application is only for iPhone and ipod touch users only, not for the ipad (yet). So, i don't know where I need to specify this option while submitting app to the apple. If anybody can help me then it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance...

**EDIT:** While submitting app to the app store I got one radio button option which is asking like **"
Do you want to limit your app to only run on devices with specific capabilities?" Yes | No.** (this question can be found just below the description field)

I don't know what to select and why..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using features that are specific to updates like iPhone OS 3.0 then you would want to limit it to anything after that build.  Otherwise users of say, the iPod Touch, who haven't upgraded would not be able to use all the features.  If your app doesn't have any device or software specific capabilities then you can just check "NO".

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter if your app isn't an "iPad app". If you submit it, it'll be submitted as an iPhone/iPod Touch app.

The iPad will be able to run it using it's scaling mode, and there's no way you can prevent this.

Unless you create your app to be universal for iPhone and iPad, this is how it will work.

Comment: @Jasarien Thanks for your reply... Can you please check my edit of question ?